# Select the last inserted row Every 1 second

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 files:
1. `chat.php`: contain chat messages.
2. `loadSingle.php`: grab last new message every 1 second.
When I get the last message it was always return and get the last one. I want to get the last message without duplicate every time.
**chat.php**:

```
function loadlastmsg(){
var fromIdl = "<?php echo $chat_from_id;?>";
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'loadSingle.php',     
    data:{fromIdl: fromIdl,},
    cache: false,
    beforeSend:function(data){

    },
    success: function(data)  
    {
        $('#mainmsgs').append(data);
    }  
});

}

setInterval(function(){
    loadlastmsg();
}, 1000);


</script>
<a href="javascript: loadlastmsg()">Load Last Message</a>
```

**loadSingle.php**:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["fromIdl"], $_POST["fromIdl"]))
{


    $chat_from_ids = $_POST["fromIdl"];


      require_once 'config/config.php';
      mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8mb4");

      $chinbox = array();
      $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM chat WHERE to_id=$userId AND from_id=$chat_from_ids OR to_id=$chat_from_ids AND from_id=$userId) ORDER BY chat.send_date DESC LIMIT 1");
      while ($chinbxsx = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $chinbox[] = $chinbxsx;
        $from_id =  $chinbxsx['from_id'];
        $subject =  $chinbxsx['subject'];
        $message =  $chinbxsx['message'];
        $get_date = $chinbxsx['send_date'];
        $senddate = date_create($chinbxsx['send_date']);
        $senddate = date_format($senddate, 'Y/m/d H:i:s');

        $from_name = $chinbxsx['from_name'];

        if($from_id != $userId){
          $from_image = $chinbxsx['from_image'];
          $msgclass = 'msgmRec';
        }else{
          $from_image = $userImage;
          $msgclass = 'msgmSend';
        }


      // if($get_date > $get_date){
            echo "<div class='msgm $msgclass'><img class='cmavsm' id='cmavsm' style='background-image: url($from_image);' /><p class='smRec'>$message</p><span class='date_span'>$senddate</span></div>";
      // }

      }


    $conn->close();


 }

?>
```

The mistake is: get the last message every 1 second. every time without stop it. I want to get the last message one time without loop the last message. thanks.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: The solution here is to find the max message ID and pass that in the next time you fetch. Reminder: Tools like [Socket.io](http://socket.io) are probably better than aggressive AJAX polling.

Comment: At a high level, a couple things to consider in your logic... (1) When making a request for the "last message", include the ID of the current "known last message".  Then the server-side code can at least filter out messages that are already known.  (2) Do you really want the *last* message, or do you want *all messages since the last known message*?  That is, what if there are *two* new messages?  Don't you want them both?

Comment: I want to get(fetch) last record every 1 second. the last record contain every chat information such as: message, isread, date, and so on.

Comment: @tadman could you please change my code into `parameterized queries` please.

Comment: You will need to save the last message ID on the client side (Javascript). Having this, you can do two things, 1) On the ajax post, send this ID and prevent que query on the server side to get a last message if the ID is equal to this one; or 2) Put similar logic on the client side (Javascript) to discard last message when the ID is equal to the latest received one.

Comment: @D.Smania Please put a fixed code?

Answer (score 1):

Using Ajax for chat will have poor performance always. You must consider using Web sockets.

See the below link for a sample

https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/

Answer (score 0):

I can't warranty this will be a fixed code, but it will give you the idea of how to discard a message on the client side if already received:

**CLIENT SIDE:**

```
<script>

/* Other code ... */

// Global variable for save the latest message ID.
var _latestMessageID = -1;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Start getting messages...

    setInterval(
        function() {loadlastmsg();},
        1000
    );
});

function loadlastmsg()
{
    var fromIdl = "<?php echo $chat_from_id;?>";
    var formData = {fromIdl: fromIdl};

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'loadSingle.php',
        data: $.param(formData),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data && data["ID"] > _latestMessageID)
            {
                $('#mainmsgs').append(data["message"]);
                _latestMessageID = data["ID"];
            }
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

**SERVER SIDE:**

```
<?php

require_once 'config/config.php';

if(isset($_POST["fromIdl"]) && $_POST["fromIdl"])
{
    $chat_from_ids = $_POST["fromIdl"];
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8mb4");
    $chinbox = array();

    $result=$conn->query(
        "SELECT *
         FROM chat
         WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id)
                     FROM chat
                     WHERE (to_id=$userId AND from_id=$chat_from_ids)
                     OR (to_id=$chat_from_ids AND from_id=$userId))
         ORDER BY chat.send_date DESC LIMIT 1"
    );

    // Since the query has LIMIT of 1 this should only loop one time.

    while ($chinbxsx = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $chinbox[] = $chinbxsx;
        $from_id =  $chinbxsx['from_id'];
        $subject =  $chinbxsx['subject'];
        $message =  $chinbxsx['message'];
        $get_date = $chinbxsx['send_date'];
        $senddate = date_create($chinbxsx['send_date']);
        $senddate = date_format($senddate, 'Y/m/d H:i:s');
        $from_name = $chinbxsx['from_name'];

        if ($from_id != $userId)
        {
            $from_image = $chinbxsx['from_image'];
            $msgclass = 'msgmRec';
        }
        else
        {
            $from_image = $userImage;
            $msgclass = 'msgmSend';
        }

        $msgID = $chinbxsx['id'];
    }

    $returnArray = array();
    $returnArray["ID"] = $msgID;
    $returnArray["message"] = "<div class='msgm $msgclass'><img class='cmavsm' id='cmavsm' style='background-image: url($from_image);' /><p class='smRec'>$message</p><span class='date_span'>$senddate</span></div>";

    echo json_encode($result);    
    $conn->close();
 }

?>
```

Comment: please contact remotely my pc if you can, by using Team Viewer. here is my ID: 489 638 077 and Password: 2572

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have the time now. But you can leave any doubt you have and i will answer when i get some time. Anyway, and like a warning, you should not publish your team viewer information in a public post.